# Multiple Factory Girl associations issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to do this association with Factory Girl..

So basically, Agency has many agents, landlords and properties. When I check my Property factory is valid, it returns false saying Account Manager and Landlord can't be blank. How do I create those associations though? When creating a property, it associates 'agency' and creates one of them, but I need the 'Landlord' and 'Agent' to be associations of 'agency' too..

Part of the problem may be that I've been staring at this for so long, so apologies if it is something straight forward!

**Models:**

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agents
  has_many :landlords
  has_many :properties
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :landlord
  belongs_to :agency
  belongs_to :account_manager, class_name: 'Agent', foreign_key: 'agent_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
end

class Agent < User
  has_many :properties
end

class Landlord < User
  has_many :properties
end
```

**Factories:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :property do
    address_line_1 "13 Fake Street"
    address_line_2 "Strange Lane"
    town "Fake Town"
    county "FakeCounty"
    post_code "PA0 0WU"
    beds 4
    baths 2
    agency

    factory :invalid_property do
      address_line_1 ""
    end     
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do     
  factory :agency do
    name "First Agency"
    telephone_number "01993 388388"
    address_line_1 "1 Fake Street"
    town "Fake Town"
    county "FakeCounty"
    post_code "BA1 4GG"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :agent, class: User do
    first_name "James"
    last_name "Smith"
    email "james.smith@gmail.com"
    password "helloworld"
    telephone_number "01935 222333"
    mobile_telephone_number "07382 928777"
    agency
  end

  factory :landlord, class: User do
    first_name "Bob"
    last_name "Builder"
    email "bob.builder@gmail.com"
    password "helloworld"
    telephone_number "01935 444777"
    agency

    factory :invalid_landlord, class: User do
      first_name ""
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I added the Landlord model based on assumptions, please check if it's ok

Comment: and your factory specifies an `agency` in your `:agent`. But this relationship doesn't show up in your model

Comment: Thank you for those additions. I'm actually using STI from the User model for the Landlord and Agent models, so the belongs_to :agency is inherited from there :)

Comment: Ah true, forgot about that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't really do these sorts of relations within factories.

In the end I have removed the associations, and am manually building the agency and any other associations first, then passing them into the build of the factory. For example:

```html
  let(:agency) { build(:agency) }
  let(:account_manager) { build(:agent, agency: agency) }
  let(:landlord) { build(:landlord, agency: agency) }
  let(:property) { build(:property, agency: agency, account_manager: account_manager, landlord: landlord ) }
```